# Posiblities to login using Windows Task schedule

Tags: batch, windows-task-scheduler

Im running automatization RPA daily with Windows Task Sheduler (WTS). It`s okay but sometimes client lock screen and it won`t work. I cant use WTS option to run if logged out because it will run in background and my automatization won`t work. Is there possiblity to loggin with .batch file? For example i run batch with WTS it will login to profile and i run next one for automatization whle logged in. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way to go is to run this whether the user is logged in or not, which runs your program without GUI. You need to fix whatever is causing it to not work. sometimes you rely on networkshares that are not mapped, so you need to map it first.

You specify what account is used to login with so the login happens at that point, its just non-interactive. You should specify a useraccount, not something like NT/SYSTEM as that may cause issues when connecting to network shares.